# javascript crossbrowser determine if user scrolld to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript

Hello how could i get in **Javascript** *(no Jquery)* an alert when the user got to the bottom of the page?
i tried based on another example here something like this but no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<div  id="bla" style="width:145px;">

 long text here

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = document.getElementById("bla");
debugger;

if( obj.scrollTop == (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight))
{
    alert("down");
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
 doctype then it sould work.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") > -1) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight == (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok")
        }
    } else {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight == (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using normal `<html>` tag at the top of your document then it should work.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight == (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    } else {
        if (document.body.scrollHeight == (document.body.scrollTop + document.body.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you is working great in IE but in Firefox popup a lot of alerts before i get to end of page and in Chrome doesn't fire any alert

Comment: using only window.onscroll = function () {
   
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight == (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok");
        }
   
}

works fine in both IE and FF .. i still have problems with Chrome .. it doesn't fire the event.

Comment: thanks .. work better now .. still in IE8 popup 2 times the second ok message

Comment: Make sure you browser mode is not Quirks Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onscroll` event of the window.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    // check scroll position
}
```