# javascript mobile crossbrowser determine if user scrolled to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile

Hello based on my question located at :

[javascript crossbrowser determine if user scrolld to the bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357728/javascript-crossbrowser-determine-if-user-scrolld-to-the-bottom-of-page)

How could i write this to be mobile compatible?

```
window.onscroll = function () {
if (document.body.scrollHeight == (document.body.scrollTop + document.body.clientHeight)) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is to help.

As you say you can get the current scrollHeight, what is happen if you 
place a anchor on bottom of the page? and use a script as

```
var curr = document.body.scrollHeight;
document.location.href = "#bottompage";
if(curr == document.body.scrollHeight) {
  alert("Bottom of page");
}
```

Comment: i need to show a list .. when you get to the end of the list it should load next 30 records that's why i need a cross browser mobile to see when i'm on the bottom of the page in order to call a function that will load next records. Looking at your example seems like always curr= document.body.scrollHeight so i will get always the alert.I don't need to send user to bottom of the page .. i need to detect when he get there in order to serve him the next 30 records...

Comment: Yes, this can be a problem, you can try to use the first 2 lines of code, and after this reset the pos by use `document.body.scrollHeight=curr` but I think this not is a good ide to do and in case for dynamic load next records I will say this is time to do this while you has 10 record left to show.

Comment: You can also try to add a event to the `<body>` as `onmouseover` and then in each event get witch element the use is on by use `var e=event.target||event.srcElement;`
This will also need you to do a loop for loop out unto you find a the target element that has a know pos.
Do not know if this work on mobiles.

Comment: in the meantime we change our mind so will not use anymore this function .. so i guess i will marke your answer as accepted for the effort, thank you